# iFrame Issue with showing content in desired iFrame size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

Within my webpage I am having issues with a iFrames. The iFrame is being used to cycle through different Webpages.

The issue I am experiencing is that it appears as only a thin bar (see picture)? Can someone help me on how I fit the cycling websites within a defined diameter? I have research around this topic as I am already working with some code found in iFrames.

[iFrame_Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk7I2.png)

Thanks in advance! -Adam

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

 <head>
 
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  
  <!-- Tab Title In Window-->
  <title>GKN BI/IT PVD Notice Board</title> 
  
  <!-- CSS Style-->
  <style type="text/css">
   body { margin:0;padding:0;font-family: Sans-Serif;line-height: 1.5em;}
   header {background: #FFFFFF;height: 100px;}
   header h1 {margin: 0;padding-top: 15px;}
   main {padding-bottom: 10010px;margin-bottom: -10000px;float: left;width: 100%;}
   nav {padding-bottom: 10010px; margin-bottom: -10000px;float: left;width: 230px; margin-left: -230px;background: #FFFFFF;}
   footer{ clear: left;width: 100%;background: #FACC2E;text-align: center;padding: 0px 0;}
   #wrapper {overflow: hidden;}
   <!--Same as 'nav' width -->   
   #content {margin-right: 230px; }
    <!-- Padding for content -->
   .innertube {margin: 15px;margin-top: 0; height: 200%; width: 200%;}
   p {color: #555;}
   nav ul {list-style-type: none;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
   nav ul a {color: #336699;text-decoration: none;}
  
  </style>
  
 </head>
 
  <!--Web banner-->
  <header>
  <center-left>
  <table width="875" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <tr>
   <td>
   <img src="Images/bi_it_banner.png"> 
   </td>
   </tr>
  <!--Web banner 2-->
   <tr>
   <td>
   <img src="Images/background.jpg"> 
   </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  
  </header>
   
 <body>
  <div id="wrapper">
  
 <main>
 
   <!--Title and iFrame Cycle-->
    <div id="content">
     <div class="innertube">
      <h1>Current Projects</h1>
      <br>
      <br>
      <!--iFrame-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
      var sites = [
      "http://ourspace.gkn/drivelive/",
      "http://ishare.driveline.gkn.com/SitePages/Home.aspx",
      "https://idash.driveline.gkn.com/josso/signon/login.do?josso_back_to=http://idash.driveline.gkn.com/applicationOverview/josso_security_check&josso_partnerapp_id=applicationOverview"
       
      ];
      
      var currentSite = sites.length;
      $(document).ready(function () {
      var $iframe = $("iframe").attr("src","http://www.google.com");
      setInterval(function() {
      (currentSite == 0) ? currentSite = sites.length - 1 : currentSite = currentSite -1;
      $iframe.attr("src",sites[currentSite]);
      }, 7000);
      });
      </script>  
 
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
      iframe {
      height: 200%;
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      }
      </style>
      <br>
      <iframe></iframe>
      <br>
     </div>
    </div>
  
 </main>
   
<!-- Code for Navigation Bar and Time&Date -->
   <nav>
    <div class="innertube">
    <!--Time/Date Function-->
  <center>
  <table width="200" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   <script type="text/javascript">
   
    <!--Date-->
    var tmonth=new Array("January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December");
    function GetClock(){
    var d=new Date();
    var nmonth=d.getMonth(),ndate=d.getDate(),nyear=d.getYear();
    if(nyear<1000) nyear+=1900;
    <!--Time-->
    var nhour=d.getHours(),nmin=d.getMinutes(),nsec=d.getSeconds();
    if(nmin<=9) nmin="0"+nmin
    if(nsec<=9) nsec="0"+nsec;
    document.getElementById('clockbox').innerHTML=""+tmonth[nmonth]+" "+ndate+", "+nyear+" "+nhour+":"+nmin+":"+nsec+"";
    }
    <!--Load into webpage and carry out function above-->
    window.onload=function(){
    GetClock();
    setInterval(GetClock,1000);
    }
   </script>
   <div id="clockbox"></div>
   
     <h3>GKN Sites</h3>
     <ul>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://ourspace.gkn/drivelive/">Drivelive</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://ishare.driveline.gkn.com/IT/SitePages/Home.aspx">BI/IT iShare</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="">Others?</a></li>
     </ul>
     <h3>Suggested Reading</h3>
     <ul>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank"  href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="#">Link 4</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank"  href="#">Link 5</a></li>
     </ul>
     <h3>External News</h3>
     <ul>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/news">BBC News</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/travel">BBC Travel</a></li>
      <li><a target="_blank" href="http://www.bbc.co.uk/weather/">BBC Weather</a></li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </nav>
  </div>
  </table>
<!-- End of code for Navigation Bar -->

  <footer>
   <div class="innertube"> 
   <marquee><img src="Images/GKN.svg.png" height="25" width="60"> Hopefully feed text from text file here</marquee>
   </div>
  </footer>
 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Is the height of your iframe set? Also, on the page in the iframe, you may need to set the viewport setting in the meta tag.